# What is an appropriate way to change property accessors on sub classes whilst maintaining polymorphism?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I have a few classes that inherit from a base class for which I wish to change the implementation of a property and method. I also require the base class and all sub classes to be be polymorphic, so I can later create a collection of any type that implements a particular interface.

When i create instances of my classes that implement an interface, I want to use properties and methods on that class (implemented by the interface), not the base class.

This is my simplified implementation of the issue that provides the desired output but does have a code smell...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IGrid one = new TextField();
        IGrid two = new SelectList();
        one.Click();
        two.Click();
        Console.WriteLine(one.Text);
        Console.WriteLine(two.Text);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IGrid {
    string Text { get; set; }
    void Click();
}

public class Control : IGrid {
    public string Text {
        get { return "Hello Control!"; }
        set { }
    }

    public virtual void Click() {
        Console.WriteLine("In the Control!");
    }
}

public class SelectList : Control, IGrid {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public new string Text {
        get {
            return "Hello Select!";
        }
        set { Number = int.Parse(value); }
    }

    public override void Click() {
        Console.WriteLine("In the Select!");
    }
}

public class TextField : Control, IGrid {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public new string Text {
        get {
            return "Hello TextField!";
        }
        set { Number = int.Parse(value); }
        }

    public override void Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the TextField!");
    }
}
```

This works but feels a little messy having an empty set in the Control class.

Is there a cleaner approach to this type of problem without compromising on specific property implementations on sub classes?

Many thanks,

Comment: IMHO, if you're not going to implement an interface, then don't pretend to implement an interface. Have some compassion for the end users of your class. Also, your example does not make sense to me, that 1. you would throw an exception if someone tries to set a string `Text` property to a non-integer value, and 2. You don't change the `Text` property when someone sets it. Do you have a more realistic example? It's completely unclear why you would want to do this, rather than just create a new interface with the additional property.

Comment: Hi Rufus. Sorry it's not clear. I'm still learning. Ultimately I want to end up with something like `List<IGrid> GridItems` then be able to add grid items of different types, such as `SelectList` and `TextField`. I would like to be able to access specific implementations of methods and properties on those classes, and not any base class. The `set` assessor that looks weird is only there to show that I want to change the implementation on sub classes. As I say, approach may be completely wrong and I'm open to better suggestions. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so first thing is first, you should not be changing another property when you set a property (like you are doing to Number from Text).  This is a huge code smell because it is a side effect.  You should always deal directly with the properties that you intend to.

```
public class SelectList : Control, IGrid {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public new string Text {
        get {
            return "Hello Select!";
        }
        // This is bad, someone after you may not know that this has a side effect
        set { Number = int.Parse(value); }
    }   
}
```

Second, a property can be virtual just like a method, so marking your Text property as virtual and overridding in a derived class will make polymorphism work the way it is intended.  "Hiding" via the new keyword would require you to cast your interface its specific class in order to get that classes implementation.

```
public class Control : IGrid
    {
        public virtual string Text
        {
            get { return "Hello Control!"; }

        }

        public virtual void Click()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In the Control!");
        }
    }
public class SelectList : Control, IGrid
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello Select!";
        }

    }

    public override void Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the Select!");
    }
}
```

Third, you do not have to have a setter on the interface.  You could just have a getter and only need to implement that.

```
public interface IGrid
    {
        string Text { get; }
        void Click();
    }
```

Finally, if you are ALWAYS going to override a method or property and NEVER going to create the base class directly (with a new) then you should consider using an abstract class if you have shared implementation (EG at least one method or property you do not change) or don't bother with the base class because you are not using any of the code anyways.

```
// Abstract class
public abstract class Control : IGrid
{
    // Property that is not overridden but is shared
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public abstract string Text
    {
        get;

    }

    public abstract void Click();
}
public class SelectList : Control
{
    // Don't need the Number property here, base class has it

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello Select!";
        }

    }

    public override void Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the Select!");
    }
}

// Need everything in this class, but if it is all different anyways
//  then base class is kind of a waste
public class TextField : IGrid
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello TextField!";
        }
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In the TextField!");
    }
}
```